# asp.net CollapsiblePanelExtender ajax toolkit

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, collapsiblepanelextender

i have a website with a left sidebar and content area. All is well. I would like to be able to collapse the sidebar using the ajax control toolkit CollapsiblePanelExtender.

I have used the code below but the sidebar shows and the content area is below it. its like the panel actually has a width that messes things up but im not sure.
What i want is that the siebar and content area show as normal and when a user wants to the sidebar collapses and the content fills the full available area of the screen.

any help appreciated

**HTML Code**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="MyTestWebsite.Site1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/FAInteractions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="590; URL=Login.aspx" />
    <title>MyTestWebsite</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="application,control" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="application,control" />
    <meta name="description" content="Control Application" />
    <link href="assets/css/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/modalBackground.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="True">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="HeaderWrapper">
                <div id="Header">
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="pnl">
                        <div style="float: left;">
                            Panel1
                        </div>
                        <div style="float: right;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear: both">
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="ContentWrapper">
                <ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender1" runat="server"
                    CollapseControlID="Panel1" Collapsed="false" ExpandControlID="Panel1" TextLabelID="Label1"
                    CollapsedText="Show" ExpandedText="Hide" ExpandDirection="Vertical" TargetControlID="Panel2"
                    ScrollContents="false">
                </ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
                    <div id="Sidebar">
                        <asp:Accordion ID="AccordionMenu" CssClass="accordion" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
                            HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected" ContentCssClass="accordionContent"
                            runat="server" Width="95%" Height="800px" FramesPerSecond="30" TransitionDuration="250">
                            <Panes>
                                <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPaneConfigureDevice" runat="server">
                                    <Header>
                                        Configure Device</Header>
                                    <Content>
                                        <asp:Button CssClass="Button" ID="btnConfigureDevice" runat="server" Text="Configure Device"
                                            Width="100%" OnClick="btnConfigureDevice_Click" />
                                    </Content>
                                </asp:AccordionPane>
                            </Panes>
                        </asp:Accordion>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
                <div id="Content" style="border: thin solid #666666" class="Tabs">
                    <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainerMain" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="4" Width="100%"
                        Height="100%" CssClass="" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                        <asp:TabPanel ID="Tab_Configure_Device" runat="server" HeaderText="Tab_Configure_Device">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div class="TabControls">
                                    <p>
                                        Howdy, I'm in Section Tab_Configure_Device .</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="TabsAction">
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:TabPanel>
                    </asp:TabContainer>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of wrapper -->
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
Main CSS File */

#HeaderWrapper 
{
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-left:0px;    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#99CCFF'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#9CF)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFF,  #9CF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */   

    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    border-bottom:thin solid #FFFFFF;

}

#Header
{    

    width:1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 



}

#ContentWrapper 
{
    width:1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 


}


/* sidebar */

#Sidebar {

    float: left;
    width: 184px;
    padding: 0px;
    height:800px;
    border: thin solid #666666;
    padding:0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-right:6px;
    margin-left:0px;    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFFFFF'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#FFF)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFF,  #FFF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ 


}


/* end of sidebar -->

/* content */

#Content {
    float: left;
    width: 824px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px; 
    min-height:800px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFFFFF'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#FFF)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFF,  #FFF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ 
}
/* End content */



/* End content */
html,body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:1.5em;  
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#003366', endColorstr='#FFFFFF'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#036), to(#FFF)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #036,  #FFF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ 
    height: 100%;   

}

/*Accordion */
        .accordion {  
            width: 100%;  
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 5px;
        }  

        .accordionHeader {  
            border: 1px solid #003366;  
            color: white;  
            background-color: #003366;  
            font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;  
            font-size: 12px;  
            font-weight: bold;  
            padding: 4px;  
            margin-top: 4px;  
            cursor: pointer;  
            border-radius: 5px;
        }  

        .accordionHeaderSelected {  
            border: 1px solid #003366;  
            color: white;  
            background-color: #003366;  
            font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;  
            font-size: 12px;  
            font-weight: bold;  
            padding: 4px;  
            margin-top: 4px;  
            cursor: pointer; 
            border-radius: 5px; 
        }  

        .accordionContent {  
            background-color: #FFFFFF;  
            border: 1px solid #003366;  
            border-top: none;  
            padding: 5px;  
            padding-top: 4px; 
            border-radius: 5px; 
        }  

/*End Accordion */

/* Busy Form */

.updateProgress  
{  


    border-radius: 5px;

}

/* Busy Form */

/* Logo */

#DivLogo
{

    float: left;    
    margin-top:5px;  
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-right:6px;
    margin-left:0px;    
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px;     
    width: 140px;
    height: 25px;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;  
    font-size: 20px;  
    font-weight: bold; 




}

/* End Logo */


/* Menu */


#DivMenu
{

    float: left; 
    clear: left;
    margin-top:12px;  
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-right:6px;
    margin-left:0px;

    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:5px; 

    width: 205px;
    height: 25px;
    border-width: 1px;  
    border-style: solid;  
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}







.Menu
{  
    list-style: none;
            font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;  
            font-size: 12px;  
            font-weight: bold;  
            margin-top:1px;  
}

.Menu ul
{  
    background:#003366;

}

.Menu ul li
{
    background:#003366;
    text-align:center;
    /* set width if needed.*/
    width:100px;
}

.Menu ul li a
{

    color: White;
    padding: 4px 2px 4px;
    padding-left:8px !important;

}

.Menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-image: none;

}

.Menu ul li a:hover
{
    color: Black;
    background:White;
}

.Menu ul li a
{
    color: White;
}



/* End Menu*/




#DivUserDetails
{


    float: right;

    margin-top:13px;  
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-left:0px;

    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-left:5px; 

    width: auto;
    height: 25px;
    border-width: 1px;  
    border-style: solid;  
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;

}



/* About Modal */


#AboutContainer {


position:absolute;
    height:300px;
    width:440px;
    top:10%;
    left:35%;    

}


#AboutInputContainer {

position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    top:10%;
    left:20%;
    color:Black;


}



/* End About Modal */

/* Signoff Modal */



#SignoffContainer {


position:absolute;
    height:200px;
    width:440px;
    top:10%;
    left:35%;    

}


#SignoffInputContainer {

position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    top:10%;
    left:20%;
    color:Black;


}




/* End Signoff Modal */



/* Error Modal */

#ErrorContainer {


position:absolute;
height:300px;
min-height:300px;
max-height:100%;

    width:440px;
    top:10%;
    left:35%;
    overflow:auto;


}


#ErrorInputContainer {

position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    top:10%;
    left:20%;
    color:Black;


}

#lblErrorCode
{


}


#lblErrorMessage
{

}

#lblExMessage
{




}


/* End Error Modal */


/* Grids */

.mGrid { width: 100%; background-color: #fff; margin: 5px 0 10px 0; border: solid 1px #525252; border-collapse:collapse;font-family:Verdana; font-size:12px;
        table-layout:fixed;

           }

.mGrid td { padding: 2px; border: solid 1px #c1c1c1; color: #003366; }

.mGrid th { padding: 4px 2px; color: #000000; 
            background: #99CCFF; font-size: 0.9em;border: solid 1px #c1c1c1;   
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#99CCFF'); /* for IE */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#9CF)); /* for webkit browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFF,  #9CF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */

          }

.mGrid .alt  { background: #fcfcfc; }


.mGrid tr.data-row:hover { background-color:#FFFFCC; color:white; }

.mGrid .pgr {background: #FFCC33;

             }

.mGrid .pgr table { margin: 5px 0;}

.mGrid .pgr td { border-width: 0px; 
                 padding: 2px; 

                 font-weight: bold; 
                 color:Black; 
                 line-height: 12px;
                 font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;  
                 font-size: 12px;
                 border-radius: 5px;
                padding-left: 4px;     
                  padding-right: 4px; 


             }  

.mGrid .pgr a { color:Black; text-decoration: none; }

.mGrid .pgr a:hover { color:Black;  text-decoration: none; }



.pgr span
{
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;

  background: White;
  border-radius: 5px;


}








/* End Grids */






.TabControls

{




    margin-top:2px;  
    margin-bottom:2px;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-left:2px;

    padding-top:2px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    padding-right:2px;
    padding-left:2px;     
    width: auto;

    border-width: 1px;  
    border-style: solid;  
    border-radius: 5px;

        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#99CCFF'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#9CF)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFF,  #9CF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ 
    height:120px;



}



.TabsAction

{

        margin-top:2px;  
    margin-bottom:1px;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-left:2px;

    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:1px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px;     


        border-width: 1px;  
    border-style: solid;  
    border-radius: 5px;

        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#99CCFF'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFF), to(#9CF)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFF,  #9CF); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ 
    height:120px;



    height: 660px; 
    overflow: auto;
    /* Wrap all words in the grid so it fits in the window      */
    word-break : break-all;

}



/* TextBox */


.Textbox
{

width:auto;
        padding:2px;
        color:Black;

        text-align:left;
         -moz-border-radius: 5px;
         -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
         -khtml-border-radius: 5px; 
          border-radius: 5px; 
}

.Textbox:focus
{

 background-color:#FFCC33;


}



/* End TextBox */



/* Button */


.Button
{


         -moz-border-radius: 5px;
         -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
         -khtml-border-radius: 5px; 
          border-radius: 5px; 

          text-align:left;


          padding-left:22px;
          margin-top:1px;
          margin-bottom:1px;       
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-image: url(/assets/img/action.gif);
               background-position:3px 50%
}

.Button:hover
{
          background: #FFCC33;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-image: url(/assets/img/action.gif);
           background-position:3px 50%


}


/* End Button */
```